# Does electron version above 20.0.2 support ffi-napiu

Tags: electron, ffi

I am trying to use electron with ffi-napi, everything works fine when I use the version **20.0.2** of electron.
When I update electron to **20.3.9**
there is a error saying `error in native callback`

I've tried both **20.3.9** and **23.0.0**
I got same error as above
only working version is 20.0.2

Does electron still support **ffi-napi** above the version **20.0.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffi-napi doesn't work after electron version 20.3.8

check this out:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35504

https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/238

A simple way to use ffi-napi is to keep your electron version under 20.3.8